# How can I use this jQuery plugin with my custom Spotify Application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, spotify, html5-audio

I currently have a jQuery plugin I am working with that is setup to use songs / tracks like this:

```
//Using an audio object
var a = new Audio();
a.src = 'somesong.mp3';
customPlayer.load( a );
```

It also supports these options:

```
//Using an audio element on the page
customPlayer.load( document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0] );

//Using a config object and you only have one encoding
customPlayer.load({ src: 'somesong.mp3' });

//Using a config object, and you have an ogg and mp3 version
customPlayer.load({ src: 'somesong', codecs: [ 'ogg', 'mp3' ]});
```

I am trying to figure a way to use it with a Spotify track!... Any thoughts / suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Spotify's API doesn't support HTML5 audio in any way, which includes both playing external audio from mp3 files or similar and using the HTML5 audio element to control the player. The Spotify player API simply instructs the client to play the track you want rather than hosting it in a HTML5 audio element.

The only way to do what you want would be to create a wrapper class that has the same interface as the jQuery Audio class, but calls Spotify APIs instead.